# How to make a low pass filter in scipy.signal?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I have several questions on making a lowpass filter in python/scipy.signal. Would appreciate any answers.

1. I'm trying to understand how [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) works. Does it take the filter coefficients and multiply them by the data values, so that for `data[500]`, it'll do

```
for b in range(0,len(coeff)):
    filtered = filtered + data[500-b]*coeff[b]
```

What's the difference between doing that and what it's doing?

2. I also don't understand how the number of taps affects when it starts filtering. For different number of taps I see it starting at different values on the data. I assumed it'll start only after it has the necessary coefficients. In my example I have 683 coefficients from `scipy.signal.firwin`, but the filter starts at 300-400, as you can see in the image [Firwin lowpass filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbAV9.png) (filter is in blue; sinewave is in red; x goes from 0-1000)

```
from scipy import signal

a = signal.firwin(683, cutoff = 1/30, window = "hamming")
t = signal.lfilter(a,1,sig)
```

3. With an fs=1, cutoff = fs/30, I get a lowpass filter with firwin that is delayed a lot as shown by the image above. What can I do to improve the delay?
4. How would changing the sampling rate affect the filter?
5. I've found two methods online to approximate the number of taps:

```
import math

(2/3) * math.log10(1/(10*ripple*attenuation)) * fs/transition_width
((-10*math.log10(ripple*attenuation) - 13)/(14.6)) * fs/transition_width
```

Which is a better approximation?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The signal-processing questions are more on-topic at [Signal ProcessingSE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/). Anyway you can and should answer 1. and 2. for yourself by declaring a very small filter with simple coefficients `a`, `b` and a signal `x` that's just an array of all-ones. Also there are 1840 hits for *"scipy.signal.lfilter" tutorial*, please skim them.

Comment: Also, I tagged this `scipy` and added some links, but please add the missing `import` statements to make this reproducible. Don't assume that most Python programmers hav ever heard of 'firwin'.

Comment: As someone who grappled with signal-processing APIs on and off for years, I learned *experimentation is always your friend*, always assume the documentation is skimpy, unreliable, outdated or plain missing. Always try your own experimentation. Aggressively simplify hyperparameters and coefficients as much as needed to get a result. You may well find bugs, please do file bug reports or docbugs, but don't get blocked on them.

Comment: @smci I've added the imports. I had already checked the signal.lfilter tutorials, but still couldn't get an idea of what it was doing. I also checked the source code, but that was even more confusing. So I tried the array of all-ones, and I can see that the filter is starting from around 683, which makes sense, but with the sinewave as shown above, it starts before. In both cases though, it overshoots before 683, which means it's not filtering as suggested in my question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I'm trying to understand how [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) works.

`scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, x)` implements ["infinite impulse response" (IIR), aka "recursive", filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response), in which `b` and `a` represent the IIR filter and `x` is the input signal.

The `b` arg is an array of `M+1` numerator (feedforward) filter coefficients, and `a` is an array of `N+1` denominator (feedback) filter coefficients. Conventionally, `a[0]` = 1 (otherwise the filter can be normalized to make it so), so I'll assume `a[0]` = 1. The nth output sample `y[n]` is computed as

```txt
  y[n] = b[0] * x[n] + b[1] * x[n-1] + ... + b[M] * x[n-M]
                     - a[1] * y[n-1] - ... - a[N] * y[n-N].
```

The peculiar thing with IIR filtering is that this formula for `y[n]` depends on the previous `N` output values `y[n-1]`, ...,  `y[n-N]`; the formula is a recursive. So in order to start this process, conventionally the filter is "zero initialized" by assuming `y[n]` and `x[n]` are zero for n < 0. This is what `scipy.signal.lfilter` does by default.

You can also use `scipy.signal.lfilter` to apply a "finite impulse response" (FIR) by setting `a = [1]`, as you have done in question 2. Then there are no recursive feedback terms in the filtering formula, so filtering becomes simply the convolution of `b` and `x`.

> 2. I also don't understand how the number of taps affects when it starts filtering. For different number of taps I see it starting at different values on the data. I assumed it'll start only after it has the necessary coefficients. In my example I have 683 coefficients from scipy.signal.firwin, but the filter starts at 300-400, as you can see in the image Firwin lowpass filter (filter is in blue; sinewave is in red; x goes from 0-1000)

`scipy.signal.lfilter` starts filtering immediately. As I mentioned above, it does this (by default) assuming `y[n]` and `x[n]` are zero for n < 0, meaning it computes the first output sample to be `y[0]` is computed as

```txt
  y[0] = b[0] * x[0].
```

However, depending on your filter, it could be that `b[0]` is near zero, which could explain why nothing appears to happen at the beginning.

A good way to inspect the behavior of a filter is to compute its "impulse response", that is look the output resulting from passing the unit impulse `[1, 0, 0, 0, ...]` as input:

```
plot(scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, [1] + [0] * 800))
```

Here is what I get for `b = firwin(683, cutoff = 1/30, window = "hamming")`, `a = [1]`:

[image: Impulse response]

We can see several things from this plot: the impulse response is very small at first, then rises and oscillates, with its peak at sample index 341, then symmetrically decays again to zero. The filter has a delay of 341 = 683 // 2, that is, half the number of taps that you specified to `firwin` when designing the filter.

> 3. What can I do to improve the delay?

Try reducing the number of taps 683 to something smaller. Or if you don't require filtering to be [causal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_filter), try [scipy.ndimage.convolve1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve1d), which shifts the computation so that the filter is centered:

```
scipy.ndimage.convolve1d(sig, firwin_filter, mode='constant')
```

> 4. How would changing the sampling rate affect the filter?

For most filter designs, provided the cutoffs are less than 1/4th the sample rate, the exact sample rate has little effect. Or in other words, it's usually not a problem unless the cutoffs are moderately close to the Nyquist frequency.

> 5. I've found two methods online to approximate the number of taps.

I'm not familiar with these formulas. Beware that the number of taps needed to achieve target characteristics depends on the particular design method, so pay attention to what context those formulas assume.

Within `scipy.signal`, I'd suggest using `kaiserord` together with `firwin` or `firwin2` for a target amount of ripple and transition width. [Here is their example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.kaiserord.html#scipy.signal.kaiserord), in which the 65 is the stopband ripple in dB and `width` is the transition width in Hz:

> Use [`kaiserord`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.kaiserord.html#scipy.signal.kaiserord) to determine the length of the filter and the parameter for the Kaiser window.
>
> ```
> >>> numtaps, beta = kaiserord(65, width/(0.5*fs))
> >>> numtaps
> 167
> >>> beta
> 6.20426
> ```
>
> Use [`firwin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin) to create the FIR filter.
>
> ```
> >>> taps = firwin(numtaps, cutoff, window=('kaiser', beta),
>                   scale=False, fs=fs)
> ```

---

**Edit:** With other designs, `kaiserord` might get in the right ballpark, but don't rely on that necessarily achieving a target amount of ripple or transition width. So a possible general strategy might be an iterative process like this:

1. Use `kaiserord` to get an initial estimate of the number of taps.
2. Design the filter with that many taps.
3. Use [scipy.signal.freqz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) to get the filter's frequency response.
4. Evaluate how close the response magnitude is to the desired response. Namely, over the passband, compute the max absolute difference from one, and over the stopband, compute the max absolute difference from zero.
5. If the response is not close enough, increase the number of taps and return to step 2. Otherwise, see if you can get away with decreasing the number of taps.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That was very clear!
If I were to use another filtering method besides firwin, what would you suggest to approximate the number of taps? kaiserord also?

Comment: Good question. I think kaiserord would make a decent starting point, and it could be iteratively improved from there. Please see my edit above.